# is there any class diagram for java development tool

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am try to draw class diagram for a new language for that I need class diagram of jdt.is there any sample class diagram of Java development tool is available ?

it should contain eclipse views, action set , wizard

Comment: Do you need a tool or an example class diagram?